# Can I take a feat multiple times?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e

Taking some feats like Adopted Ancestry or [Adapted Cantrip](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=66) multiple times might be beneficial.

I could not find anything against taking feats several times in the [Feats](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=180) section, but some feats specifically state that they can be taken multiple times, like [Assurance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=756) and [Armor Proficiency](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=755).

Can I take Adopted Ancestry for more than one race for example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### You can select a feat multiple times if it says so in the "Special" section.

In the rules for "Reading Rules", we see:

> **Special** Usually this section appears in feats you can select more than once, explaining what happens when you do.

For example, one of the feats you mentioned, Assurance, can be taken multiple times, as the feat description states:

> **Special** You can select this feat multiple times. Each time, choose a different skill and gain the benefits for that skill.

Comment: I had assumed so, but is there any rule that a feat can't be taken multiple times in general? I'm not sure the Special section quoted is enough to prove the negative.

Comment: @brandon It's written right here. "Usually" is indicating that the typical use for the **Special** section of the feat description is to denote that a feat can be taken more than once, but that there may be other uses for that section. What is is *not* saying is "When a feat can be taken more than once, usually it says so in the **Special** section".