# I know I can't choose to take a feat multiple times; can I gain a feat multiple times via other means?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e

[Now we know we cannot *take* the same feat multiple times.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/194729/can-i-take-a-feat-multiple-times)

What about when something else gives it to us?
Imagine you are a Human who took the general feat Adopted Ancestry (Halfling). Then on level 5, can you take an Ancestry feat (Cultural Adaptability) which *happens* to give you the general feat Adopted Ancestry?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Probably not.

As I quoted in the linked question, feats you can select multiple times tell you happens when you do so:

> **Special** Usually this section appears in feats you can select more than once, explaining what happens when you do.

It seems clear enough to me that the *intent* is that you can only take a feat multiple times if the rules tell you what happens when you do so. This isn’t *clearly* spelled out, hence your question, so the GM has room to rule otherwise.

Comment: Technically, my read would be that you get both, but in the absence of such a special rule, the second one doesn’t do anything. This was [explicitly the case in D&D 3.5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/61859/4563) (and thus PF 1e), and could matter in [a very few corner case](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/86956/4563)s (in 3.5e, don’t think it ever did in PF).